# In Haskell, how could I embed one Free monad in another one?

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad

I have two Free monads for different operations in different contexts. However, one (`major`) DSL needs to contain another one (`action`) if the specific operation is in the context:

```
import Control.Monad.Free

data ActionFunctor next = Wait Timeout next
                        | Read URI next

instance Functor ActionFunctor where
  fmap f (Wait timeout next)  = Wait timeout (f next)
  fmap f (Read uri next)      = Read uri (f next)

type Action = Free ActionFunctor


data MajorFunctor next = Log LogText next
                       | Act Action next
                       | Send Message

instance Functor MajorFunctor where
  fmap f (Log text next)    = Log text (f next)
  fmap f (Act action next)  = Act action (f next)
  fmap f (Send message)     = Send message

type Major = Free MajorFunctor
```

The issue is, GHC will complain `MajorFunctor` that the `Action` in `Act Action next` is a kind of `(* -> *)`, not just a type. This is because in the `data ActionFunctor` definition it should accept a `next` as the type parameter, and in the `Act Action` line it contains no such parameter. But even the message is clear to me, I'm not sure if I should declare such extra type parameter in the `Major` functor as well:

```
data MajorFunctor actionNext next = ...
```

It looks weird because only one data constructor will use the parameter, while such exposing will turn every `MajorFunctor` into `MajorFunctor actionNext` and it looks totally exposes too much details. So I took a look at `FreeT` transformer to see if it is what I want. However, in my case I only need to call `Action` interpreter when the DSL program has such operation, not every `bind` in the monadic program, so I'm also not sure if a transformer is a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Act` constructor, you can embed an `Action a` and then continue with the `next` step depending on the `a`. You can do this by using an existential to tie the two together:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data MajorFunctor next = Log LogText next
                       | forall a. Act (Action a) (a -> next)
                       | Send Message

instance Functor MajorFunctor where
  fmap f (Log text next)    = Log text (f next)
  fmap f (Act action next)  = Act action (fmap f next)
  fmap f (Send message)     = Send message
```

Answer (score 7):

A simpler solution, which doesn't need an existential, is to embed the `next` parameter inside the `Action`.

```
data MajorFunctor next = Log LogText next
                       | Act (Action next)
                       | Send Message

instance Functor MajorFunctor where
  fmap f (Log text next) = Log text (f next)
  fmap f (Act action) = Act (fmap f action)
  fmap f (Send message) = Send message
```

This says "When you execute the `Action` it'll return a `next`", whereas @Cactus's solution says "When you execute the `Action` it'll return something (of unknown (existential) type) which can (only) be *turned into* a `next`".

[The co-Yoneda lemma](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.0.1/docs/Data-Functor-Coyoneda.html) says that these two solutions are isomorphic. My version is simpler but Cactus's may be faster for some operations such as repeated `fmap`s over large `Action`s.

Comment: Nice solution! What a clever application of Coyoneda. ^-^